# HTML - Table head width not working

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried with this.

```
<th style="width:500px;overflow:hidden;">
```

If I have a large description It is going outside the table &  I want to fix it.

```
 <div class="Tablecontent">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div style="min-height:300px">
            <table class="table table-hover" >
                <thead class="tableHeadDesign">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:40px; overflow:hidden;">S.No.</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th style="max-width:500px;overflow:hidden;">
                            Description
                         </th>
                        <th>Size  </th>
                        <th>Status </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="tableBodyDesign">
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in media |filter:searchText">
                        <td>$index </td>
                        <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.Description }}</td>
                        <td > </td>
                        <td>{{x.Status}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg popbtn ViewBtn" value="View Detail"></a></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I want to fix Description Column.

Comment: Post complete HTML, with FIDDLE will be great

Comment: I just use your provided HTML and created a fiddle and its working fine, even without your inline style.
https://jsfiddle.net/kronosneer/y1rdng7q/embedded/result/

Comment: have you see my example may be it will help you  @Anony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use text ellipsis** 
see this example

```css
td{
  max-width:20px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
table{
width:100%
}
```

```html
 <div class="Tablecontent">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div style="min-height:300px">
            <table class="table table-hover" >
                <thead class="tableHeadDesign">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:40px; overflow:hidden;">S.No.</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th style="max-width:500px;overflow:hidden;">
                            Description
                         </th>
                        <th>Size  </th>
                        <th>Status </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="tableBodyDesign">
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in media |filter:searchText">
                        <td>1 </td>
                        <td>name</td>
                        <td>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
                        <td >dsdsdsdsds </td>
                        <td>Status</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg popbtn ViewBtn" value="View Detail"></a></input>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for text-overflow?

```
<td style="max-width:500px; display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:clip; white-space:nowrap;">
  {{ x.Description }}
</td>
```

Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/59166290/aan0s31t/15/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve...
Actually I had fixed the  and forgot to set the fixed size of  :p